# Bootstrap buttons not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried implementing this snippet into my web page and for some reason the buttons aren't responsive and don't toggle between active/notActive when clicked. It works fine in my jsFiddle, but the same code doesn't work on my web page. I have the proper imports for JQuery and Bootstrap because the rest of my form utilizes tools using these frameworks and are working properly. Any suggestions on what could be going wrong? Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/collint25/4pq266cz/. I won't post the JavaScript or CSS just because it'd be copied verbatim from the fiddle.

```
<div class="form form-horizontal">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Submitter's Information</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label> 
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subName" id="subName" value="<?php echo $name ?>" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display: none">
                <label for="subTitle" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subTitle" id="subTitle" placeholder="Title" value="<?php echo $title ?>" maxlength="50" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display: none">
                <label for="subDept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Department:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-validation="required" name="subDept" id="subDept" placeholder="Department:" value="<?php echo $department ?>" maxlength="20">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label for="subGUID" class="col-sm-3 control-label">AU Email/GUID:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subGUID" id="subGUID" data-validation="email" data-validation-error-msg="You did not enter a valid e-mail" value="<?php echo $wouserid . "@auburn.edu" ?>" maxlength="50">    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-validation="required" name="subPhone" id="subPhone" placeholder="Phone Number" value="<?php echo $phone ?>" maxlength="20">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subSupervisor" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Are you the Nominee’s Direct Supervisor?</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="happy" data-title="Y">YES</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="happy" data-title="N">NO</a>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="happy" id="happy">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Except that you *should* copy the JS and CSS here because it's required to have all code relevant to a question in the question itself. Best if it's a [mcve]. If jsFiddle goes down (again) that link will be worthless for later visitors to this question. You can get a very similar experience to fiddle by using the Stack Snippets (the `<>` on a page) button.

Comment: Looking at the console in the fiddle - clicking the buttons seems to change both the active state and the value of the hidden input. I too have used this code in the past and it seems to be working here.